# How to import a string into my .tsx file from module with a relative reference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stenciljs

I make a online course for building a website with [StencilJS](https://stenciljs.com/docs/introduction), [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/de) and the [IonicFramwork](https://ionicframework.com/). I am new in this and I am biting my teeth with a problem:

They import the API `"https://swapi.dev/api"` as a string into the file `app-people.tsx` with

```
import { API_URL } from '../../helpers/api';
```

I know it is an import of a module with a relative reference.
But I don't get `API_URL` imported! Visual Studio shows me only the error:

`Cannot find module '../../helpers/api' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Where do I need to create the folders `'../../helpers/api'`?

What must the file with `API_URL` contain? What file type must be used(`.ts`, `.js`, `.d.ts`)?

This is my code in `app-people.tsx`:

```
import { Component, State, h, ComponentDidLoad} from '@stencil/core';
import { API_URL } from '../../helpers/api';                           // to import the Basic-API

//...

@Component({
  tag: 'app-people',
  styleUrl: 'app-people.css',
})

export class AppPeople implements ComponentDidLoad {

  @State() people: Person[] = [];
  @State() loading = true;

  private apiUrl = `${API_URL}/people`;                              // here is API_URL used:
//...
```

From my root folder `star-wars` to `app-people.tsx` is this path:

```
star-wars/src/components/app-people/app-people.tsx
```

I have already tried many combinations but can't come to a solution. Please for tips here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the path `../../helpers/api` and that your component is located in `star-wars/src/components/app-people`, then you need to create a TS file `star-wars/src/helpers/api.ts` which would contain the following:

```
export const API_URL = 'https://swapi.dev/api';
```

The import path is relative to the location of the file with the import statement.